# git diff shows difference after git pull from a branch

Tags: git

I have a `dev` branch and a `bugfix/a` branch. 
I want to sync up my `bugfix/a` with `dev`, so I do a

```
git pull origin dev
```

from my bugfix/a branch, but after that, I still see `git diff` shows differences:

`git diff --name-only dev..bugfix/a`

why `git pull` doesn't merge all the changes from dev to my branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your dev branch is up to date?

When you do `git pull origin dev` on another branch, only that other branch is getting updated, not the local `dev` branch.

If you will checkout your `dev` branch and if it is a tracking branch, it will show a message on the lines of branch is behind by so many commits.

Even if it is not a tracking branch, you will still need to update your `dev` branch locally so that it matches the changes on the `origin` branch.

In future, you can avoid this confusion by checking out dev, pulling in the changes in dev, and then checking out your bugfix branch, and merging changes there:

- `git checkout dev && git pull origin dev`
- `git checkout bugfix/a && git merge dev`